# Date in Time Series Does not Line up with X-axis

Tags: r, plot, time-series, sequence, axes

I am trying to plot water temperatures collected from a stream at 15-minute intervals starting on 4/7/2015 and ending on 11/23/2015. I would like to have the x-axis have labels at each tick mark as, "Apr", "May" etc. through "Nov".  The code that I wrote makes a good looking figure but the temperature readings are misaligned with the x-axis tick marks; they start at April 1, 2015 as a opposed to April 7, 2015; therefore, all the temperature readings are shifted 7 days either than they should be. To put it another way I would like to x-axis to start on April 1, but the data to start on the date when they were collected.I think it has something to do with how I am sequencing the times and apply the ticks, but I am not sure how to correct it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

```
#Load Data
trib<-read.csv("C:\\r.data\\trib.csv",header=TRUE)    

#Index Time
    trib$DateTime<-as.POSIXct(strptime(trib$DateTime,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))

#Create Time Series
trib.xts<-xts(trib,order.by=trib$DateTime)

#Example Data
 DateTime                      Temp
22666 2015-04-07 13:30:00      NA
22667 2015-04-07 13:45:00      2.983
22668 2015-04-07 14:00:00      3.142
22669 2015-04-07 14:15:00      3.274
22670 2015-04-07 14:30:00      3.354
22671 2015-04-07 14:45:00      3.433
22672 2015-04-07 15:00:00      3.485
22673 2015-04-07 15:15:00      3.670
22674 2015-04-07 15:30:00      3.749
22675 2015-04-07 15:45:00      3.827

#Plot
par(mfrow=c(1,1))

margins <- par(mar=c(2,2,1,1)+0.1)
omargins <- par(oma=c(2,2,0.5,0.5)+0.1)

Temp.lab=seq(0,30,by=5)
Temp.ticks=seq(0,30,by=5)
plot(trib.xts$Temp,axes=FALSE,auto.grid=FALSE,col="gray",ylim=c(0,30),main="Stream Name",cex.main=0.8,lwd=1)
axis(2,at=Temp.ticks,labels=format(Temp.lab,scientific=FALSE),ylab="Temperature (C)",las=1,cex.axis=0.8)

times <- time(trib.xts$DateTime["2015-04-01/2015-11-15"])
ticksm <- seq(times[1], times[length(times)], by = "months")
month.lab = c("Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov")
axis(1, at = ticksm, labels = month.lab, tcl = -0.5,cex.axis=0.8,xlab="Month")
mtext("Temperature (°C)",side=2,line=3,las=3,cex=0.8)
mtext("Month",side=1,line=3,cex=0.8)
```

Comment: I don't think you got your index column input correctly. That column of integers on the left side do not look as though you have gotten the index to be the date-times you should have been attempting. The `plot.xts` method will be using the index as the x-axis positioning. This is a further indication of the need to use `dput` as the output function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but would I index the date-times correctly? Thank you again.

Comment: Assuming you meant to type "how would I better the index", then I cannot advise. You have not shown how this data-object was created.

Comment: The data came a from a .csv file with two column headings: DateTime and Temp. I've updated my code to include reading in the .csv file. Thank you.

Comment: I still suspect problems at the initial input of data. Post `dput(trib)`. My tests of `read.csv` with an initial value of NA and no specification of colClasses shows that that column you think are numbers could well be factor-classed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it, assuming you don't mind a ggplot solution.

```
# Let's first make SampleData to your specifications:
trib.xts <- data.frame(DateTime = seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2015/04/07 13:30:00",Format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", timezone ="CEST"),
                                             as.POSIXct("2015/11/23 13:00:00",Format="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", timezone ="CEST"),
                                             by="15 min"))
# Then add temperature, a bit warmer in summer.
trib.xts$Temp <- 2*sin(month(trib.xts$DateTime))+rnorm(22083,mean=7,sd=2)

#Now, we need ggplot and scales
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

#then make a plot
(plot1 <- ggplot(trib.xts, aes(x=DateTime, y=Temp)) +
  geom_point(col="gray",shape=1) +
  theme_bw(24) +
  ggtitle("Stream Name") +
  ylab("Temperature (°C)") +
  xlab("Month"))

# Now set the breaks, labels and x-limits as you please
(plot1 <- plot1 +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 month", 
               labels=date_format("%b"),
               limits = as.POSIXct(c("2015-03-30","2015-11-25"), timezone="CEST")))
```

[image]
Notice that my x-axis is in Dutch. Yours will be in your own language, but you can change this by changing `Sys.setlocale`.

Comment: Thank you for a solution RHA, but how would I do it from reading in the .csv to the final plot the non-ggplot way? Thank you again.

Comment: @mkRuser I don't know. I'm a ggplot-lover. The trouble with an index is that R has no way of knowing were to start. You could try adding all dates from 1-apr to 7-apr with NA. But i would go for ggplot...